# Как создать ORM описание/валидацию уникального ключа из двух полей?

Tags: mysql, битрикс

Есть `Entity\Validator\Unique` класс для проверки на уникальность. Только он проверяет уникальность конкретного поля. Как проверять, если у меня при создании таблицы уникальный ключ создан из двух полей `unique ux_table_name (PROPERTY_ID, XML_ID)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я так понял способа никакого нет. Поэтому создаем таблицу с помощью SQL запроса с файла install, а потом делаем что-то типа

```
new Entity\StringField('YOUR_FIELD_CODE', array(
    'required' => true,
    'validation' => array(__CLASS__, 'validateFunction'),
    'title' => Loc::getMessage('YOUR_FIELD_CODE_FIELD'),
) ),
```

и собственно вручную производим валидацию

```
public static function validateFunction()
{
    return array(
        function ($value, $primary, $row, $field) {
            $error_message = Loc::getMessage('ENUM_ENTITY_DUPLICATE_ERROR');
            if($bad_val)//не прошли валидацию
               return new Entity\FieldError($field, $error_message, 'UNIQUE_CHECK');
            else
               return true;
        },
        new Main\Entity\Validator\Length(null, 200),
    );
}
```